# issues with fractions

Tags: fractions

I have:

```
\usepackage{nicefrac }
\begin{align*}
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2y+1}\sqrt{2 \pi}}  \exp \left( -y-\nicefrac{1}{2} \right)  &&\forall y \in  [-\frac{1}{2} , \infty) \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2y+1}\sqrt{2 \pi}}  \exp \left( -y-\frac{1}{2} \right)  &&\forall y \in  [-\nicefrac{1}{2} , \infty) 
\end{align*}
```

Both of these seem somewhat unsatisfactory. Could anyone help me get the best display for the `1/2` after the `\exp (` and also after the `\in [`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Fractions

I'd just use the normal `\frac` or `\tfrac`. For display style maths they still look the best. I would use `\nicefrac` (or similar) only (if at all) in text maths.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\frstfrac{\frac{2}{\sqrt{2y+1}\sqrt{2 \pi}}} % just a shortcut
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  &= \frstfrac       \exp \left(            -y - \frac{1}{2}\right)  && \forall y \in  \left[- \frac{1}{2}, \infty\right) \\
  &= \frstfrac \cdot  e^{                   -y - \frac{1}{2}}        && \forall y \in  \left[-\tfrac{1}{2}, \infty\right) \\
  &= \frstfrac \cdot  e^{           -  \left(y + \frac{1}{2}\right)} && \forall y \in  \left[-\tfrac{1}{2}, \infty\right) \\
  &= \frstfrac \cdot  e^{\textstyle -\!\left(y + \frac{1}{2}\right)} && \forall y \in  \left[-\tfrac{1}{2}, \infty\right) \\
  &= \frstfrac       \exp \left(            -y - 1/2 \right)         && \forall y \in  \left[-       1/ 2 , \infty\right)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: different outputs of the fraction]

## `\smash`

Also, consider using `\sqrt{\smash[b]{2y+1}}\sqrt{\smash[b]{2 \pi}}` in your denominator for better roots.

To quote from the `amsmath` documentation:

> With the amsmath package `\smash` has optional arguments `t` and `b`, because occasionally it is advantageous to be able to “smash” only the top or only the bottom of something while retaining the natural depth or height.

Compare:

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{2}{\sqrt{\smash[b]{2y+1}}\sqrt{\smash[b]{2 \pi}}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2y+1}\sqrt{2 \pi}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: smash example]

The top bar of the root is aligned different and even the lower point is not on equal heights.

### *LaTeX Companion*

The *LaTeX Companion* has a very elaborated text about `\smash` and its uses. The first two examples (licensed under the [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt)) are shown here. Take a close look at the root's lower end and the top bar.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$ \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}            + \sqrt{z} $ \par
$ \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{\mathstrut y} + \sqrt{z} $ \par
$ \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{\smash{y}}    + \sqrt{z} $ \par
$ \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{\smash[b]{y}} + \sqrt{z} $

\[
   \sqrt{ \frac{a+b}{         x_j   } } \quad
   \sqrt{ \frac{a+b}{  \smash{x_j  }} } \quad
   \sqrt{ \frac{a+b}{{}\smash{x_j  }} } \quad
   \sqrt{ \frac{a+b}{  \smash{x_j+b}} }
\]
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: square root example]
[image: fraction example]

Comment: What does the recommended ``\smash`` command do?

Comment: Thank you. As I see these outputs, I like the `\left[-\tfrac{1}{2} , \infty\right)` but I don't like either the `\left[-\tfrac{1}{2} , \infty\right)` (seems clumsy: the 1/2 is too big) or either of the two `e^{}` (too small). On balance I would perfer the `e^{-\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)}` but I would like to find some middle ground (if possible). Thanks again, much appreciated.

Comment: @BenediktBauer I expanded my answer. I remember reading a very elaborated text about the use of `\smash` but can't find it at the moment.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: You might be referring to this TUGBoat entry: [A complement to `\smash`, `\llap`, and `\rlap`](http://math.arizona.edu/~aprl/publications/mathclap/). Even if not, it's a handy reference.

Comment: @Werner Well, I wasn't, but it is indeed helpful when we're talking about “best display” (OP). The text I actually meant was a subsection of the _LaTeX companion_ (“Ghostbusters™”).